# Not getting internet on my 12.10 Even if Wifi connection is established

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I am not getting internet even after wifi connection being established.I have two operating systems installed on my sony vaio(E Series,VPCEH15EN) laptop.Most amazing point is I can browse net on windows but can't browse it in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Have you checked your DNS?  Add the output of `nm-tool` to you question?

Answer (score 0):

Have u checked for additional drivers for your Wireless device. Try so it should work out.
So also can u avail of simple file sharing. Try to do so with another wireless based system.

Post the output of lspci -vnn

User